# DCOS Service stuck for no apparent reason

Tags: mesos, dcos

My service is stuck most likely because of resource unavailability

```
dcos marathon debug summary /my-service
RESOURCE     REQUESTED  MATCHED  PERCENTAGE  
ROLE         [*]        5 / 6    83.33%      
CONSTRAINTS  ---        5 / 5    100.00%     
CPUS         4          0 / 5    0.00%       
MEM          416        0 / 0    ---         
DISK         10         0 / 0    ---         
PORTS        [0]        0 / 0    ---
```

I am 100% sure that the `cpu` and `memory` I am requesting are available;

Furthermore, what is this role constraint not being satisfied?

edit: this is **despite** the fact that when hovering over the GUI it says for the CPUs (which I cannot find) that `Requested: 0.4` / `Received 4`

and this stil fails..

edit: [here](https://gist.github.com/pkaramol/1ea7f7c3120683bfae21537c6bc4e5b0) is a gist with extended mesos slaves' info

Answer (score 0):

In DCOS you can easily debug stuck deployments. [Here](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.12/monitoring/debugging/stuck-deployment/) is the guide how to do it.

Basically, you need to go to [debug page](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.12/monitoring/debugging/gui-debugging/#debugging-page) and you should see why resource offers are declined.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Furthermore, what is this role constraint not being satisfied?

Roles, also called "resource roles", help to separate different groups of resources from each other. For example, in a standard DC/OS cluster, all resources of public nodes are reserved to a role `slave_public`.

When Marathon receives a resource offer, it takes into consideration a role to which these resources are reserved. In your case, Marathon declined one resource offer because the resources didn't belong to the default role called `*`.

Please, read more about resource roles in [Mesos documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/roles/).

I reviewed the output of the `/mesos/slaves` endpoint from the gist and found out that in your cluster all of the agents but one do not have available resources for your service:

`10.11.17.23`, `10.11.17.250`, `10.11.17.41`, `10.11.17.72`, and `10.11.17.123` have only 2 CPUs.

`10.11.16.12` does have 4 CPUs but all of them are reserved for the `spave_public` role.

`10.11.17.46` has 8 CPU in total, 2.5 CPU reserved for the `slave_public` role, and the rest 5.5 should be indeed enough for the `/my-service`. It seems like, for some reason, this Mesos agent doesn't send resource offers to the Master.

Check the logs of this agent (`journalctl -u dcos-mesos-slave`) for any errors. The fact that it was registered in the cluster 4 hours later than the other agents (13:39:44 vs. 09:42:51) is a bit suspicious.

Check master logs (`journalctl -u dcos-mesos-master`) if Mesos sends any resource offers from this agent to the Marathon.

Check Marathon logs (`journalctl -u dcos-marathon`) if Marathon receives resource offers from this agent and if it does, the reason for the decline.

[This Mesosphere blog article](https://mesosphere.com/blog/debugging-dcos/) can give you some more ideas.